existing activity field referring to form activities
I apologize if this is an obvious answer. There is still so much I need to learn!
I'm trying to build a submission form in FormBuilder that would submit a new individual and a new activity. When organizing the fields on the layout pane, I noticed that I couldn't split the activity's fields to be above and below the individual fields so I added a second activity and used the "Existing Activity" field to point it back to Activity 1.
This... did not work. Whenever I do a test submission it logs a submission but none of the entities are actually created in CiviCRM.
Am I misunderstanding the utility of the "Existing Activity" field? Or do I have them in the wrong order (does the individual have to be created before the activity?) Or is there some other variable that I just don't know to worry about?



Instead of adding a second activity entity, you can add a second fieldset for the original activity. Note that you can drag a "Fieldset for Hotline" into the form. That's what you need.

I knew it had to be something embarrassingly easy that I just hadn't figured out yet! Thank you so much!
